# MYSQL DATE RANGE and TIME RANGE

Tags: mysql

Counting fax completed by Graveyard Shift 10pm - 7am,

date and time are in different field

```
    $stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM fax WHERE
                date BETWEEN CURDATE() and CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                    and time >= '22:00:00' and time <= '7:00:00' 
                        and shift='GY' 
                            and complete=1");                
    $stmt -> execute();
    echo $GY_COMP = $stmt -> fetchColumn();
```

This query always resulting to 0 but it has data.

Can someone help me with my query? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The way you are getting count from db is wrong. You should select the count already, not the records to count them after.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's a bad habit. Can u check my answer below I have another problem in this statement

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem was in your time comparison: you effectively filtered out everything with your `time >= '22:00:00' and time <= '7:00:00'`

Hope this helps: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45108/7/0

```
SELECT * FROM fax
WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() and CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
and
((time >= '22:00' and time <= '23:59')
or
(time >= '0:00' and time <= '7:00'))
and shift='GY' 
and complete=1
```

Comment: Max can u check my answer I need help in IF ELSE in MYSQL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Max for the time comparison, 
I already made changes to my syntax

```
SELECT count(*) FROM fax
    WHERE ((date = CURDATE() and (time >='22:00' and time <= '23:59')) 
           or (date=CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and (time >= '00:00' and time <= '7:00'))) 
                  and shift = 'GY'
                           and complete = 1
```

now my problem is RANGE of shift is today 10pm to tom 7am.

But my syntax above still get wrong when it change date

HELP IN USING IF STATEMENT in MYSQL

IF YES(SELECT THIS) ELSE IF (SELECT THIS) 
HOW to properly use IF ELSE in MYSQL statement

```
SELECT count(*) FROM fax
  IF 
  (date = CURDATE() and (time >='22:00' and time <= '23:59')
     THEN 
       SELECT count(*) FROM fax
       WHERE ((date = CURDATE() and (time >='22:00' and time <= '23:59')) 
       or (date=CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and (time >= '00:00' and time <= '7:00'))) 
       and shift = 'GY' and complete = 1
   ELSE IF
   (date = CURDATE() and (time >= '00:00' and time <= '7:00')
          THEN
            SELECT count(*) FROM fax
            WHERE ((date = CURDATE() and (time >= '00:00' and time <= '7:00')) 
             or (date=CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and (time >='22:00' and time <= '23:59'))) 
             and shift = 'GY' and complete = 1
```

Comment: Please move you addition to your initial question: do not delete the original text, but append your new text after "UPDATE" text. Also you'd better describe what your goal is: i.e. something like "I keep ... in a table with fields ... I want to get all the ... For example, for this sample records ... I want to get this output..."