# MYSQL SELECT IF SELECT ELSE IF SELECT QUERY

Tags: mysql

[MYSQL DATE RANGE and TIME RANGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349047/mysql-date-range-and-time-range/)

I ask this question a while ago and I need help in mysql SELECT IF SELECT ELSE IF SELECT in my query about getting complete and pending logsheet for Graveyard shift which has a range  TODAY 10PM to TOM 7AM. Is this possible? Any suggestion? it will count number of pending logsheet

```
SELECT count(*) FROM faxlogsheet 
    IF 
   (date = CURDATE() and (time_received >='22:00' and time_received <= '23:59')
    THEN 
        SELECT * FROM faxlogsheet
             WHERE ((date = CURDATE() and (time_received >='22:00' and time_received <= '23:59')) 
                 or (date=CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and (time_received >= '00:00' and time_received <= '7:00'))) 
             and shift = 'GY' and complete = 0
        ELSE IF
            (date = CURDATE() and (time_received >= '00:00' and time_received <= '7:00')
           THEN
             SELECT * FROM faxlogsheet
                WHERE ((date = CURDATE() and (time_received >= '00:00' and time_received <= '7:00')) 
                   or (date=CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and (time_received >='22:00' and time_received <= '23:59'))) 
                   and shift = 'GY' and complete = 0
```

Comment: your table shema maybe ??

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45108/7/0

Answer (score 0):

they are totally two different queries , you should use here 2 queries as you cant use select statment inside IF clause.

first query

```
SELECT * FROM faxlogsheet
                     WHERE ((date = CURDATE() and (time_received >='22:00' and time_received <= '23:59')) 
                       or (date=CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and (time_received >= '00:00' and time_received <= '7:00'))) 
                     and shift = 'GY' and complete = 0
```

second query

```
SELECT * FROM faxlogsheet
                        WHERE ((date = CURDATE() and (time_received >= '00:00' and time_received <= '7:00')) 
                         or (date=CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and (time_received >='22:00' and time_received <= '23:59'))) 
                         and shift = 'GY' and complete = 0");
```